# Java text field history in applet

Tags: forms, caching, applet, field, history

I have a simple Java applet with several text fields for input.
I would like to be able to somehow cache what the user enters into these fields so that next time they run the applet, they can make a selection from a list of previous inputs.

I have been searching forums and sites and cannot find any way to do this for applets.

Does anyone have a suggestion or a kick in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this in a browser, you could try using cookies.

Answer (score 1):

As well as cookies, here are a few more possibilities.

- HTML5 offers [Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) which can be accessed from the applet using JS.
- An applet running in a Plug-In 2 JRE can be deployed using [JWS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and use the `PersistenceService` to store data.  Here is a [demo. of the `PersistenceService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).
- A trusted applet can read/write the local file-system, but probably overkill for this.

Comment: I tried using CookieManager and Cookie Handler but they do not seem to add my cookies to the browser for later use. I am most likely using them wrong or missing something. 

 CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
 CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
 CookieStore cookieJar =  manager.getCookieStore();
 
 URL url = new URL("http://"+this.host);       
 HttpCookie ck = new HttpCookie("name", "value");
 cookieJar.add(url.toURI(), ck);

Comment: 1) Ask @Valkyrio re. the cookies.  I never use them.  2) Put code as an edit to the question, and use code formatting to make it readable.